# How to write "When current animation finished"?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a model with animation controller. I set the states and parameters for transitions between them. Now I need to make the model play its animations in order I want.

I can use:

```
GetComponent.<Animator>().SetBool("someparameter",true);
```

to uncheck currently checked parameter and check another parameter after current animation finished.

How can I make a condition for when the current animation finished?

Examples I'm finding are related to *animation* component (not *animator*), or they are too complicated for me, while I need a simple way I can understand and use quickly.

Comment: fyi: stackoverflow tends not to like "fluff" with questions (thank you, urgent, etc.) -- I removed it for you

Comment: @AnthonySottile <strike>Thank you!</strike>

Answer (score 0):

unity3d supports the events and triggers within the macanim, have a look the links below

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/750785/mecanim-trigger-event-at-end-of-animation-state.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("YourAnimationName"))
{
    // Avoid any reload.
}
```